# How to remove java5 from ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-11.04, java-5

I want to remove java5 completely from my ubuntu 11.04 system. On executing java -version, it showing -

```
java version "1.5.0"
gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.4.5
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

How can I remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove completely that java version you need to remove the packages that contain it, see a list of packages with:

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep jre
```

In this way you see what `jre` packages you've installed. Then you can remove the packages with:

```
sudo apt-get remove old_jre_package
```

Anyway a **better solution** is to make more `JDK` versions coesist, in Ubuntu is easy to do it. You can use the `update-alternatives` command. So you can install another `JDK` and switch between the `jdk` versions with the alternative tools:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

For more options see the man page `man update-alternatives`.

Comment: @Alropo executing first dpkg --get-selections | grep jdk command showing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can search all the jre package in your system by running this command

```
sudo aptitude search jre
```

Remove it using this command

```
sudo apt-get remove sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin sun-java6-fonts
```

You can also try this command to remove all the java files in your system

```
sudo aptitude remove '~njava'
```

Comment: Since you are using 5 just rename your java versions to what you want to remove.

Comment: On running first and third command showing sudo: aptitude: command not found, second command with java 5 showing - Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Virtual packages like 'sun-java6-jre' can't be removed
Virtual packages like 'sun-java6-plugin' can't be removed
Virtual packages like 'sun-java6-fonts' can't be removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 311 not upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

You should try script [oab java](https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6).

Answer (score 0):

Yes the better solution is to make more JDK versions by using "update-alternatives" command.

After that you can also set PATH using the command.

> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_11 or /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_38
>   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH